# ArrayList.contains("text") throws NullPointerException?

Tags: java, android, arraylist, nullpointerexception

I'm to trying to make an android app where I accept input from the user using the speech Recognition server. I'm capturing the results in a ArrayList as follows :

```
matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
```

matches is declared globally as :

```
ArrayList<string> matches;
```

Now I want to check if the user has spoken a particular word. So I do this :

```
if(matches.contains("TextToBeDetected")) { }
```

But the line above throws a NullPointerException.

Please help.

P.S Yes, I'm a Java and Android newbie.

Comment: ArrayList<string> should be ArrayList<String>. And what is matches being set to in your getStringArrayListExtra method?

Comment: @Selvin: I think you mean OP. And there's no need to be mean to the newbie.

Answer (score 2):

Obviously, your matches is null. As per the Intent documentation, http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29
getStringArrayListExtra returns null if the key is not found in the bundle.

Test for nullity before testing if it contains anything

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as though `getStringArrayListExtra` is returning `null` ([the docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getStringArrayListExtra%28java.lang.String%29) say it will if there is such `ArrayList` value found), and so when you try `matches.contains("TextToBeDetected")` it fails because you're trying to dereference a null reference. You'll want to check the return value from `getStringArrayListExtra` to make sure it's not `null` before you use it. E.g.:

```
matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(
                    RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
// ...
if (matches != null) {
    if (matches.contains("TextToBeDetected")) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you see the docs [Android.Content.Intent.GetStringArrayListExtra](http://androidapi.xamarin.com/index.aspx?link=M%3aAndroid.Content.Intent.GetStringArrayListExtra%28System.String%29) It says

> the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or null if no ArrayList value was found.

You need to check for the list being null before setting it to matches.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `matches` is allocated?
Try this, and look at your logcat output:

```
if (matches == null) {
    Log.d("YourAppName", "matches is null!");
} else if (matches.contains("TextToBeDetected")) {
    Log.d("YourAppName", "matches does contain TextToBeDetected");
} else {
    Log.d("YourAppName", "matches does not contain TextToBeDetected");
}
```

Comment: comments like this (which do not resolve PO's problem) should be added as comments, not answers.

Comment: I figured the user might want to have some test code, as s/he mentioned s/he is a newbie.

Comment: That gives you a good reason to answer in a comment, not an answer :)

Comment: That may give me a good reason, but that doesn't give me formatting options :-) is it so bad that I answered? I think it's the point of this whole website.

Answer (score 0):

```
data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS)
```

will return the value of an item that previously added with putExtra() or null if no ArrayList  value was found. In your case, maybe it returned null